# In my Blazor server side app I cannot change the seleceted menu color in the sidebar menue navigation. How can I do it?

Tags: navigation, blazor-server-side, sidebar

In my Blazor server side app I am using the following Navigation in the side menu bar. I have taken it from the Blazor sample project. The first 2 menues have no submenues (not expandable) The third one has submenues (expandable). Due to the default settings when one of the two menues are selected their colors change to red. But this is not working on the third menu.

1.What setting should I change or add in the css for changing the selected submenu also to red color? (In the nav-link class of the site.css there is nothing defined)

2.How can I change the home icon beside the menues?

```
<NavLink class="nav-link"   href="logs" Match="NavLinkMatch.Prefix">
  <span class="oi oi-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> Error Log
</NavLink>

<NavLink class="nav-link" href="connect2" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">
  <span class="oi oi-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> Connect
</NavLink>


<NavLink class="nav-link" Match="NavLinkMatch.All" @onclick="()=>expandSubNav =   !expandSubNav">
  <span class="oi oi-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> Windows WMI
</NavLink>

@if (expandSubNav)
{

<NavLink class="" href="wmi_general">
    <span class="sub_menu">General</span>
</NavLink>
<br>

<NavLink class="" href="wmi_eventlog">
    <span class="sub_menu">EventLog</span>
</NavLink>
<br>

<NavLink class="" href="wmi_programs">
    <span class="sub_menu">Programs</span>
</NavLink>
}
```

Comment: [Polite] You need to start responding to questions you have already posted on here.   You have a trail of questions that you have posted and then done nothing with. This is not a one way street.  You need to respect the fact that responders try and answer your question for free!

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis  Tahnk you for the warning. I will do my best to do the needed actions.  But I have few question to act correctly. So would be happy if you could support. 1) I have lots of questions where I didn't get any answer. What action should I take in this case? 2) I have questions that are answered but where I could not get the correct answer. How should I take action for that? 2) I have also questions that are answered just with comments not with answers. In this case I answer over comment that this was the solution. What should I do else here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. Questions without answers are normally because: you haven't been clear enough, you have asked an impossible question, your question is naïve and answerer's don't want to get into a long discussion, or no one reading the question knows the answer.

Comment: 2. Comment on the answer if it doesn't answer the question.  Why?  Someone has taken the time to post the answer.  It's often because you haven't defined the question well enough, or provided enough information on the context.  People generally don't write wrong answers on purpose.  In general only downgrade answers that are patently wrong, not as a result of you not providing enough information.  Marking down answers that answer the question, but don't solve you problem will soon get you a bad reputation.

Comment: 3. Comment back that the information in the comment resolved your problem, so please add it as an answer.  When they do, make it as the correct answer.  People often comment when they are unsure of the context and want to make some suggestion.  You can't mark down a comment.

Comment: Try using the [Help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) or [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) when you have similar questions about Stack Overflow in the future.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis  Thank you so much for the detailed answer. As I said I will do my best and recheck my old entries and take your suggested actions.